# Why the interface sqlite3_get_table in SQLite C Interface is not recommended

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

`sqlite3_get_table` is defined as below:

```
int sqlite3_get_table(
  sqlite3 *db,          /* An open database */
  const char *zSql,     /* SQL to be evaluated */
  char ***pazResult,    /* Results of the query */
  int *pnRow,           /* Number of result rows written here */
  int *pnColumn,        /* Number of result columns written here */
  char **pzErrmsg       /* Error msg written here */
);
```

As it said in the document, it can get a result table convenient and is implemented as a wrapper around sqlite3_exec().

But it is now not recommended:

> This is a legacy interface that is preserved for backwards compatibility. Use of this interface is not recommended.

But if I use `sqlite3_exec`, I need to write a extra callback function. It is more complex。

So my question is what the main problem of this interface is? Why it need to be deprecated?

For more information see http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/free_table.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problems with `sqlite3_get_table` are that all values are converted to strings, and that memory must be allocated for all result records.

You are supposed to use the [sqlite3_prepare_v2](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html)/[sqlite3_step](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html)/[sqlite3_column_xxx](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html)/[sqlite3_finalize](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) functions.

Comment: But we can use `sqlite3_free_table` to release the result records, does it?

Comment: Yes, but the memory has to be allocated all at once.

Comment: Does allocating all at once affect the program too much?